# How do I redefine the class of a variable programmatically?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

Ok, so I have 2 classes, Note and HeldNote. HeldNote inherits from Note and adds only 2 variables, plus a different way of setting visual dimensions. I have an array of an undefined amount of items, with each item defined as a member of class Note.

Occasionally during my program, I want one of these items in the array to be a HeldNote rather than a Note, and I do not know which one until the program is running.

VB.Net seems fine with me declaring array(i) = New HeldNote but then wont let me access the variables that HeldNote has but Note does not. Using Breaks in the program leads me to believe that array(i) is not actually being redefined as a HeldNote rather than a Note.

So, my question is, how can I make array(i) a HeldNote, rather than a Note?

I'm using VB.net 2008.

Edit: I asked my Teacher about this problem and he said he didn't know and told me to look it up. I couldn't anything online (had been looking since before i asked him) so I've come here for help.

Comment: Why are you using VB2008?

Comment: Its a school project, and for some reason my school decided that is what we'd be using.

Comment: This is why you should prefer Aggregation over Inheritance. Imagine you only have one `Note` class and one `NoteVisualProperties` class. Instead of inheriting, the `Note` class has one instance of `NoteVisualProperties`. If you have a "normal" Note this instance could be null or defined with default values. In case of your "HeldNote" you would set the extra variables and dimension stuff via the properties object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array of Note (better use a List(Of Note) if you are unsure about the size) can store both Note and HeldNote because the latter derives from the first.

But, when you store an HeldNote in the array it is not automatically transformed in a Note, it is still an HeldNote, what you need is to try casting it back to an HeldNote

For example

```
Sub Main

    Dim X(2) As Note

    X(0) = New Note() WIth {.Note = "A Message"}
    X(1) = New HeldNote() With {.Note = "Held Message", .Author = "Steve"}


    Dim h As HeldNote

    h = TryCast(X(0), HeldNote)
    If h Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("X(0) is NOT an HeldNote")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(h.Author)
    End If

    h = TryCast(X(1), HeldNote)
    If h Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("X(1) is NOT an HeldNote")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(h.Author)
    End If
End Sub

Public Class Note
    Public Note As String
End Class

Public Class HeldNote 
    Inherits Note
    Public Author As String
End Class
```

In  thisway you still have your HeldNote without using an array of Object that is something to avoid because you loose all the strong typing allowed by a specific Note array (In an Object array you could store anything. A Button or a String makes no difference)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and seems like a better solution than declaring everything as an Object (as you explained).

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1) Change your design and have just one class rather than one that inherits from another.

2) Declare your array as type Object. Each element of an Object array can be of a different type. This way you can assign each element's type at runtime.

```
Dim notearray As Object() = New Object() {New Note(), New HeldNote(), New HeldNote(), New Note()}
```

Comment: Option 2 actually sounds perfect. Thanks you. (I want to use option 1 because a requirement for this is using class inheritance)

Comment: Sorry but declaring an array of type Object is like driving a Ferrari with 20 mp/h on a german Autobahn. You completeley miss the power of OO concepts like Polymprphism, Aggregation, Inheritance and the really mighty concept of Generics...

Comment: If I were your teacher, I wouldn't give you a high score, using an Object array ... An Object's array it's like the Mary Poppins bag

Comment: hmm OK, Steve seems to have given an answer that makes sense and avoids that. thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the objection is to using Object arrays. I've done stopwatch tests to compare their performance to other methods of achieving the same end and what I have found is that they stack up pretty well if not better.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a code issue, it's almost a OO question.

*"I have an array of an undefined amount of items, with each item defined as a member of class Note."*

Then all of them are "Note". You can create class instances so:

```
Note theNote = new HeldNote()
```

but you can't "downgrade" a instance on execution declared so:

```
Note theNote = new Note()".
```

If you need "randomly" a type change, you can create a ListOf(HeldNote).
Then, you can decide the real type so:

```
Dim aList as new ListOf(HeldNote)
aList.add(new HeldNote())
aList.add(new HeldNote())
aList.add(new HeldNote())

Dim oNote as Note 
oNote = Ctype(aList(0),Note) 

Dim oNote as HeldNote 
oNote = aList(1)
...
```